# Rails Call Controller Action From the View of Another Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and making a project that shows travel deals to Users. The general flow is:

My root path is /deal/index

1. If a user is not logged in, show all Deals (deal#index view)
2. If a user is logged in, show all Deals (deal#index view) but add a heart to deals that the user has saved.

I'm struggling to implement the second piece. On page load of deals (/deal/index), I want to

- Check if user is logged in
- If yes, call saveditems/userID to see if deal is saved by user
- Add heart to the deal but stay on the same page

For each deal, I have added

```
<% if current_user %>
<% link_to 'saveditems', 'saveditems#show',{:uid => current_user.uid}
```

but this only works when clicked.

Deals are not user specific but for everyone.

Is there a way that this call to the saveditem#show controller action is done without the click? I also think this may be easier to do in Javascript. Especially because I later want the user to later be able to click the heart icon and toggle adding / deleting from saved item list.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really know the MVC framework. Since the model is available across controllers and views, I can just use that instead of links and calls.

Also, a call can be triggered by using Javascript event.